# C division answer

Tags: c, division

I'm attempting to learn C but I'm having difficulty manipulating a given code. A user chooses between Squaring a number and Shrinking (dividing by 2). I can get the function Shrink to successfully return a result if the input and output remains an integer. However, I need the output to return as a float or double and I cannot get it to work. I'm stumped at this point. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Feralix

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
/* variable definition: */ 
   int intValue, menuSelect, Results;
   intValue = 1;
      // While a positive number
while (intValue > 0)
{   
     printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");
     scanf("%d", &intValue);
   if (intValue > 0)
   {
     printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Shrink \n: ");
     scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
     if (menuSelect == 1)
     {
       // Call the Square Function
       Results = Square(intValue);
       printf("Square of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results);
     }
     else if (menuSelect == 2)
     {
       // Call the Shrink function
       Results = Shrink(intValue);
       printf("Shrink of %d is %f\n",intValue,Results);
     }
     else 
       printf("Invalid menu item, only 1 or 2 is accepted\n");
     }     
   }     
return 0;
}
/* function returning the Square of a number */
int Square(int value)
{
   return value*value;
} 
/* function returning the Shrink of a number */
float Shrink(int value)
{
   return value/2.0;
}
```

Comment: You have a few problems. I'll give you some hints. What type of variable is Result? Float or int? How is it declared? How did you use it in your printf statement?

Answer (score 0):

`Results` is an `int`, so you'll lose any decimal places that got computed by `Shrink` when you assign what `Shrink` returns to it.  One possible solution would be to declare `Results` as a `float`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've spent an hour manipulating this and looking for an answer. Such a simple thing to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

The function indeed returns a float, 
You just need to declare Results varaible as a float instead of int..

```
float Results;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I couldn't determine what I was doing wrong and couldn't locate an example. The code runs now.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said results is declared as an integer type. You'll have to change the type of Results.

Also heads up:
 You'll have to change the format specifier of results in for printf in (menuSelect==1).
 Also your else won't run if you select a negative number so the user won't know they can't select negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've spent an hour manipulating this and looking for an answer. Such a simple thing to overlook. I'll also attempt to change printf, it's yet another item I was overlooking.